# wordpress blog. too many redirect error on chrome, blank page on FF

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress blog and it was working correctly but suddenly I get blank page on FF when I try to browse to mydomain/wp-admin. on Chrome I get error too many redirect. when I browse to the site itself it open fine.

I disabled all plugins and removed most of them but that did not solve my problem.

I change permalink to default and that solve the problem but I need to use pretty url (postname)

my .htaccess file with permalink set to postname

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks

**I found the problem** 
I was placing directory password on mydomain.com/wp-admin for extra security. but why that cause too many redirect error ???? any one ?

Comment: Let me know an exemple how you want the final URL

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 sorry I cant provide url. but where I can get log error ?

Comment: I found the problem I was placing directory password on mydomain.com/wp-admin for extra security. but why that cause too many redirect error ???? any one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem I was placing directory password on mydomain.com/wp-admin for extra security. but why that cause too many redirect error ????

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using hosting with Windows Operating System..
Windows OS doesnot allow you to write .htaccess file..