# redirected you too many times error on logging to word press

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Hello everybody so iam trying to log-in to my Wordpress site but it is returning `redirected you too many times.` Error and i tried solving it using this tutorial https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/  but removing my .htaccess didn't help

Note: This problem happened only after moving my WordPress from my old site to another and I had already changed the optian siteurl and homeurl from my Database

Checked recently those questions: [wordpress blog. too many redirect error on chrome, blank page on FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527545/wordpress-blog-too-many-redirect-error-on-chrome-blank-page-on-ff?rq=1) (i didn't create any extra protection for wp-admin directory...)
please some help @everyone

my .htaccess file: https://downloads.br-gaming.cf/htaccess.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your .htaccess you have a lot of rewrite rules which overlap.

for instance, you are forcing all non-www to www and SSLand down in the file you also force subdomain traffic on SSL.

I would start by removing the lower portion of the files (Any part after  `#Prevent directory listings (No index)` ) and add them as needed.

It may also be the way your DNS cnames and hostnames are setup

Comment: currently iam getting some Apache ERRORs because of my SSL Handler script `/home/domaindir/.htaccess: Invalid command 'd-Proto}', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: https://www.my-site.domain` (my mod_rewrite is issued)